# update alert and counter following on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, alert

I have created a function which prints an alert following an on click on a table cell. The alert consists of a counter. I have it working where the count increments when the table cell innerHTML is changed to a certain value, and decrements when the table cell changes to another innerHTML value. However, the new count value doesn't seem to save following the increment/decrement and repeat the same process again, incrementing and decrementing the new counter value.

Is there a way that the new count value could be saved and for the alert to be updated following future o'clock events

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).html();
    var y = 1;
    if (x == "a") {
      y += 1;
      alert("New Value: " + y);
    } else if (x == "b") {
      y -= 1;
      alert("New Value: " + y);
    }
  })
})
```

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <table >
  <tr>
  <td  onclick="this.innerHTML ='a';">1</td>
  <td  onclick="this.innerHTML ='b';">2</td>
  <td  onclick="this.innerHTML ='a';">1</td>
  </tr>
   </table>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and formatted your poorly formatted code. Please add relevant HTML to the snippet to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `y` as a global variable. I got your code to work on the following snippet.

```js
var y = 1; // Global

$(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).html();
    if (x == "a") {
      y += 1;
      alert("New Value: " + y);
    } else if (x == "b") {
      y -= 1;
      alert("New Value: " + y);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.cell-button{
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ff000088;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell-button">a</td>
  <td class="cell-button">b</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update a counter when a button is clicked using the code below. What you're doing in your code is every time the button is clicked, you redefine y (which I assume is your counter) by doing `var y = 1;`. If you want it to save, remove that line.

```js
var counter = 0;

$(".click").click(function() {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click</button>
```

**Note: If you want this answer to work for your code, update your post with more html code and leave a comment on this answer.**